# Stabilization of non-autonomous 1-d wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, wave-equation, stability-theory, hyperbolic-equations

I want to ask two questions about the stabilization of the equation 
\begin{aligned}
  & {y_{tt}} = k {y_{xx}}+a {y_t}+ b {y_x}+c y , \quad (t,x) \in {\text{ }}(0,\infty ) \times (0 ,1)  \\
  & y(t,0) = y(t,1) = 0 \\
  & y(x,0) = f(x)\\
  & y_t(x,0) = g(x)
\end{aligned}
where the coefficients $k$, $a$, $b$, $c$ are functions of $(t,x)$.

- Is there exists an exponential stabilization result concerning the above equation?
- Is there a physical interpretation of the stabilization of such an equation?  Or it is just mathematics?

Comment: It was just a mistake. I mean is there any references about the asymptomatic behaviour of the solution of this equation.

Comment: @Harry49 Yes, they are smooth enough, you can also consider the Neumann boundary conditions

Comment: The constant case is not so interesting, it is just classical case, we can use the Lyapunouv functional to get an answer, the problem arise when the coefficients are time dependents.